# How to build multiple APKs at once using Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I got a big project with several flavors in it. How can I generate all the APKS at once from all my flavors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./gradlew assemble` will compile all flavors in different build types (debug, release)

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

these guys above will compile either debug or release versions of all flavors